# Shared named volume between two containers is empty in one of them

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to share a named volume between two containers like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  service1:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - certificates:/path/to/certificates
  service2:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - certificates:/path/to/customcertificates

volumes:
   certificates:
```

At the beginning, data only exists in service1-container in `/path/to/certificates`. Using volume configuration above, data in service2 in  `/path/to/customcertificates` is empty.

How to share this data from service1 to service2?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution while writing this question. It is not optimal but OK for my case. I will still post the question with an answer, because it took me a while to figure out and may help someone:

I needed to change volumes definition like this:

```
volumes:
   certificates: {}
```